# How to resize an HTML document dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I to resize an HTML document dynamically after clicking the button with JavaScript?

There is a "site-wrapper" div that decreases with `transform: scale()` after clicking the menu button. But the height of the document before clicking remains.
This is how it looks:

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
$('.hamburger').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
    if ($(this).hasClass('is-active')) {
        $('.site-wrapper').css('transform', 'scale(0.5)');
        $('.top-line').css('position', 'relative');
        $('header').css('margin-top', '0');
    }
    else{
        $('.site-wrapper').css('transform', 'scale(1)');
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you not tried just changing the width of the `site-wrapper` element? I'm assuming that this is the desired functionality anyway? Correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Please paste the HTML code along with your jQuery so we don't have to retype all of your code.

Comment: I would remove your email from that screenshot...

Comment: You can upload images inline with your post. Stack Overflow has their own imgur instance.

Comment: I can't upload images 'cause ! don't have 10 reputation

Comment: All sizes in css set in px and if I change height or width of `site-wrapper` it changes but all content inside not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the thing is `transform: scale()` is just for visual effect and do not actually resize the element. Follow the box model in inspect element to confirm the same.

So a hack to what you need could be

1. Add an immediate wrapper element to the **.site-wrapper** - (say `.fluid-site-wrapper`).
2. Add the style rule`transform-origin: top;` to the **.site-wrapper**.
3. While applying the transform: scale() rule to the **.site-wrapper**, also decrease the height of the **.fluid-site-wrapper** and vice-versa.

which would change your code to:

```
$('.hamburger').click(function(){
    var $fluidSiteWrapper = $('.fluid-site-wrapper');
    $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
    if ($(this).hasClass('is-active')) {
        $('.site-wrapper').css('transform', 'scale(0.5)');
        $('.top-line').css('position', 'relative');
        $('header').css('margin-top', '0');
        $fluidSiteWrapper.css("height",$fluidSiteWrapper.height()/2); // if scale if 0.5
    }
    else{
        $('.site-wrapper').css('transform', 'scale(1)');
        $fluidSiteWrapper.css('height, '');
    }
});
```

I would further suggest you go with adding/removing class in place of adding/removing inline styles. Also please study about chaining in jQuery and DOM Caching.